# Why doesn't Python 3's glob() return an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

One of the differences between Python 2 and 3 is that a lot of functions now return iterators/generators rather than lists, such as `range()`, `map()`, and `filter()`. Similar iterator versions of the old functions such as `xrange()` were removed.

But Python 3 still has both [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and `glob.iglob()`. Why wasn't `glob` given the same behavior as `iglob` and `iglob` removed? Was this just something that was missed or were there discussions about it and reasons behind not making the change? If so, what were the reasons given?

Note that I'm *not* asking about the difference between the two functions or when to use one over the other, nor am I asking for personal opinions about whether or not the function should be changed.

Comment: I would guess because here are still valid use cases for `glob.glob()` that would utilize a full list, rather than a generator - whereas if you don't care about being able to access all the results at once you can still use `glob.iglob()`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy The same can be said for the other functions that now return generators instead of lists.

Comment: Maybe `glob` is going to phases out in support of `pathlib` which does [return a generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)